# Mongoose : find document with subdocument filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an User like so the `id` is **NOT** the `_id`)

```
{
  id: string;
}
```

Which can create files like so

```
{
  name: string;
  author: User;
}
```

I would like to get all `Files` where the author is a given `User`, but I do not know how to use the "filter" function to do that.

So currently I do

```
const author = await this.userModel.find({ id });
return this.filesModel.find({ author });
```

Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

(I use NestJS with the Mongoose integration, the syntax used is the same as the Mongoose library)

**EDIT**

Given the `User` document

```
{
  _id: 'OVZVIbovibiugb44'
  id: 10
}
```

And the `Files` documents

```
[
  { name: "1.docx", author: ObjectId('OVZVIbovibiugb44') },
  { name: "2.docx", author: ObjectId('voisbvOVISBEIVBv') },
]
```

I would like to use the function

```
findOwned(authorId = 10) {
  const author = await this.userModel.find({ id });
  return this.filesModel.find({ author });
  // But do it only with "filesModel"
}
```

And get, as a result,

```
[
  { name: '1.docx', author: 'ObjectId('OVZVIbovibiugb44') },
]
```

Comment: @turivishal no I can't because I have oversimplified the question and adding everything would uselessely overload the question, but there should be everything you need in the question : the document relations are correctly made, as well as the structure, and the Files documents have an ObjectId() which correctly maps an User document !

Comment: I am going to add an example of the data to illustrate though :)

Comment: try [populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) or [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) into an `aggregation` query to merge collections.

Also, as your `id` is an String and your `author` is an `ObjectId` you will need one previous stage using [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

So the query is similar to this:

- `$match` stage (optional) to query only with documents you want. Like a filter
- `$project` to convert `id` String field to `ObjectId`. You can user `$set` also.
- `$lookup` to merge collection and the ouput is in a field called `files`.
- `$project` to output only `files` array from the merge.

```js
db.User.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "id": "5a934e000102030405000001" } },
  { "$project": { "id": { "$toObjectId": "$id" } } },
  { "$lookup": {
      "from": "Files",
      "localField": "id",
      "foreignField": "author",
      "as": "files" }
  },
  { "$project": { "files": 1 } }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5vZ06ROGdml)